# Getter & Setter in Entity Class + Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a database with a table `users` with fields: `user_id, username, password`, ... . I also have a table `players` with `player_name, player_position`, ... AND a FK `user_id`.

I generated my entities from my database with the following commands:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force VolleyScoutBundle xml
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities VolleyScoutBundle
```

(Didn't generate any errors ...)

But in my Users Entity I don't have a property `player` or `getPlayer()` or `setPlayer()`. Doctrine doesn't generate this. So now I would like to create it myself so I can get the player where user_id = user_id given.

I've tried it like this:

```
private $player;

/**
 * Get player
 *
 * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players
 */

public function getPlayer() {
    return $this->player;
}
/**
 * Set player
 *
 * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players $player
 * @return Users
 */
public function setPlayer(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players $player = null){
    $this->player = $player;

    return $this;
}
```

But when I try $user->getPlayer I always get null. Also when the user is in the players table. My full Users entity till so far is:

```
<?php

namespace VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_users_roles1_idx", columns={"role_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Users implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=60, nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_firstname", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userFirstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_surname", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userSurname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_email", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userEmail;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_type", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $userType;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_token", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $userToken;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_created", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $userCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_modified", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userModified;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_deleted", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userDeleted;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_lastlogin", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userLastlogin;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_confirmed", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userConfirmed;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_locked", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userLocked;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="role_id")
     * })
     */
    protected $role;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_follows_teams",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="team_id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $team;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_follows_competitions",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="competition_id", referencedColumnName="competition_id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $competition;

    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->team = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->competition = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
    }


    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * Set userFirstname
     *
     * @param string $userFirstname
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserFirstname($userFirstname)
    {
        $this->userFirstname = $userFirstname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userFirstname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserFirstname()
    {
        return $this->userFirstname;
    }

    /**
     * Set userSurname
     *
     * @param string $userSurname
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserSurname($userSurname)
    {
        $this->userSurname = $userSurname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userSurname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserSurname()
    {
        return $this->userSurname;
    }

    /**
     * Set userEmail
     *
     * @param string $userEmail
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserEmail($userEmail)
    {
        $this->userEmail = $userEmail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userEmail
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserEmail()
    {
        return $this->userEmail;
    }

    /**
     * Set userType
     *
     * @param string $userType
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserType($userType)
    {
        $this->userType = $userType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userType
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserType()
    {
        return $this->userType;
    }

    /**
     * Set userToken
     *
     * @param string $userToken
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserToken($userToken)
    {
        $this->userToken = $userToken;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userToken
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserToken()
    {
        return $this->userToken;
    }

    /**
     * Set userCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userCreated
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserCreated($userCreated)
    {
        $this->userCreated = $userCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserCreated()
    {
        return $this->userCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Set userModified
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userModified
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserModified($userModified)
    {
        $this->userModified = $userModified;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userModified
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserModified()
    {
        return $this->userModified;
    }

    /**
     * Set userDeleted
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userDeleted
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserDeleted($userDeleted)
    {
        $this->userDeleted = $userDeleted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userDeleted
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserDeleted()
    {
        return $this->userDeleted;
    }

    /**
     * Set userLastlogin
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userLastlogin
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserLastlogin($userLastlogin)
    {
        $this->userLastlogin = $userLastlogin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userLastlogin
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserLastlogin()
    {
        return $this->userLastlogin;
    }

    /**
     * Set userConfirmed
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userConfirmed
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserConfirmed($userConfirmed)
    {
        $this->userConfirmed = $userConfirmed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userConfirmed
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserConfirmed()
    {
        return $this->userConfirmed;
    }

    /**
     * Set userLocked
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userLocked
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserLocked($userLocked)
    {
        $this->userLocked = $userLocked;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userLocked
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserLocked()
    {
        return $this->userLocked;
    }

    /**
     * Get userId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles $role
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setRoles(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles $role = null)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array($this->role->getRoleName());
    }

    /**
     * Add team
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team
     * @return Users
     */
    public function addTeam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team)
    {
        $this->team[] = $team;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove team
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team
     */
    public function removeTeam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team)
    {
        $this->team->removeElement($team);
    }

    /**
     * Get team
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTeam()
    {
        return $this->team;
    }

    /**
     * Add competition
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition
     * @return Users
     */
    public function addCompetition(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition)
    {
        $this->competition[] = $competition;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove competition
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition
     */
    public function removeCompetition(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition)
    {
        $this->competition->removeElement($competition);
    }

    /**
     * Get competition
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getCompetition()
    {
        return $this->competition;
    }

    private $player;

    /**
     * Get player
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players
     */

    public function getPlayer() {
        return $this->player;
    }
    /**
     * Set player
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players $player
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setPlayer(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players $player = null){
        $this->player = $player;

        return $this;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        $this->setPlainPassword(null);
    }

    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword($plainPassword)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
    }


    /**
     * Implementation of AdvancedUserInterface method
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of AdvancedUserInterface method
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of AdvancedUserInterface method
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of AdvancedUserInterface method
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isEnabled()
    {
        // CHECK IF $this->confirmed is not null
        if($this->userConfirmed != null){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

My Players Entity:

```
    <?php

namespace VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Players
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="players", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_players_users1_idx", columns={"user_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_players_teams1_idx", columns={"team_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_players_myteam1_idx", columns={"myteam_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Players
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $playerName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_licensenumber", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $playerLicensenumber;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_position", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $playerPosition;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_birthyear", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $playerBirthyear;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $playerId;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="myteam_id", referencedColumnName="myteam_id")
     * })
     */
    private $myteam;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="team_id")
     * })
     */
    private $team;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;



    /**
     * Set playerName
     *
     * @param string $playerName
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerName($playerName)
    {
        $this->playerName = $playerName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPlayerName()
    {
        return $this->playerName;
    }

    /**
     * Set playerLicensenumber
     *
     * @param string $playerLicensenumber
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerLicensenumber($playerLicensenumber)
    {
        $this->playerLicensenumber = $playerLicensenumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerLicensenumber
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPlayerLicensenumber()
    {
        return $this->playerLicensenumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set playerPosition
     *
     * @param string $playerPosition
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerPosition($playerPosition)
    {
        $this->playerPosition = $playerPosition;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerPosition
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPlayerPosition()
    {
        return $this->playerPosition;
    }

    /**
     * Set playerBirthyear
     *
     * @param integer $playerBirthyear
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerBirthyear($playerBirthyear)
    {
        $this->playerBirthyear = $playerBirthyear;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerBirthyear
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPlayerBirthyear()
    {
        return $this->playerBirthyear;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPlayerId()
    {
        return $this->playerId;
    }

    /**
     * Set myteam
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam $myteam
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setMyteam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam $myteam = null)
    {
        $this->myteam = $myteam;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get myteam
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam 
     */
    public function getMyteam()
    {
        return $this->myteam;
    }

    /**
     * Set team
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setTeam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team = null)
    {
        $this->team = $team;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get team
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams 
     */
    public function getTeam()
    {
        return $this->team;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users $user
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setUser(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I tried adding this:

```
 /**
 * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players")
 * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="userId")
 */
private $player;
```

But it didn't do anything. For clarification, my table relation:
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
In my Users Entity Class I have now:

```
    /**
 * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
 * })
 */
private $player;
```

But it still doesn't work, it should work now, not?

Comment: Are you sure the entity is even hydrated?

Comment: Yes, the entity Players is present. Updated my begin post with the entity class.

Comment: What about the metadata for the `$players` field?  If there is none, then doctrine won't populate it.  Maybe you just didn't include that in the snippet?

Comment: And what would the metadate be? I don't really know how to do this with a FK outside of the table instead of FK inside table.

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing, Use this example.  It is self referencing, but alter it to one-to-many of 2 tables.

Comment: But it isn't a one-to-many relation. It's a one-to-one. (Updated my begin post)

Comment: When you define the `user` variable in your `Player` entity, in the annotations you are defining a `manyToOne` relationship.  If this is the case, than in your `User` entity, you should have a `oneToMany` relationship.  It will not work otherwise.

Comment: Can you validate the mappings? `app/console doctrine:schema:validate` If this reports any errors, those could well be the issue.

Comment: Yea it says: [Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file. That's because I had the player myself ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments I read you want a one-to-one association between `Users` and `Players`. You can set it up as unidirectional like this:

```
class Players
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     */
    private $user;

    // ...
}
```

This means you will have access to user from player (`$player->getUser()`). But because it's unidirectional, you *won't* have access to player from user (`$user->getPlayer()`). Doctrine is correct when *not* creating a `$player` property in `Users`.

You could define the association the other way around:

```
class Users
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="player_id", referencedColumnName="player_id")
     */
    private $player;

    // ...
}
```

You can now do `$user->getPlayer()`, but *can't* do `$player->getUser()`.

If you want both, you'll have to set it up as a bidirectional association:

```
class Players
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users", inversedBy="player")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     */
    private $user;

    // ...
}

class Users
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $player;

    // ...
}
```

PS: I highly recommend you name your classes in single form (`User` and `Player`), not in plural form (`Users` and `Players`), because an instance (object) of those classes will represent 1 user or player (not many users or players).

Comment: Thanks, but now i get the error :No mapping found for field 'user' on class 'VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users'.

Comment: The entity `Users` should not have a field `user` (it should have `player`), the field `user` should be in the entity `Players`. What exactly did you do?

Comment: It worked, thanks!Just had to change Entity\Users to Entity\Players with my User mapping.

Comment: Ahh, I made a typo that you've already found :) I've edited my answer!